# How can I easily get a list of the indexed terms from a search index in the google appengine full text search api in java?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

How can I easily get a list of the indexed terms from a search index in the google appengine full text search api in java?

I have added an issue to the team, but can someone think of an easy way to do it in the current version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't currently have a way to do that; it doesn't expose the tokenized text at any point, so it would be hard to figure out what the indexed terms are without writing your own tokenizer. Sorry!